# How to write the SVM formula in latex?

Tags: mathematics

How to write this formula in Latex?

[image]

I tried this, but it does not work and I dont know why nor k=how to improve it.

```
$frac{$$w$^{$T$}\times($x$ - $x$)$\}{$w$}$
```

Moreover, I dont know how to prite the Xpos and Xneg and the ||w||.

Can you help me please?

Comment: •   [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

• Note this is a Q&A site, not a please do this for me service. What do you have so far.

Comment: Thank you @albert! I improved my question.

Comment: I would recommend reading a good basic introduction to latex. You should not be going in and out of math-moce like that. `$\frac{w^{T}(x_{\mathrm{pos}}-x_{\mathrm{neg}})}{\lVert w\rVert} = \frac{2}{\lVert w\rVert}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would load `newtxtext, newtxmath, mathtools` and `bm` (to have boldmath), define the `\norm` command with

```
   \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}\lVert\rVert
```

and code the formula as

```
\[\bm{\frac{w^T\bigl(x_{\textbf{\scriptsize pos}}-x_{\textbf{\scriptsize neg}}\bigr)}{\norm{x}}=\frac{\text{2}}{\norm{w}}} \]
```

[image]

Comment: I have two suggestions. First, the fraction numerator on the RHS should not be in bold. Second, we might consider loading the appropriate fonts, e.g., by `\usepackage{mathptmx}`.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked the details. For the font, I'd prefer `newtx`, which will be more complete.

Comment: I would use LuaLaTeX and `unicode-math` when you can, and PDFTeX with 8-bit legacy fonts when you have to. To get math that looks like Times with `unicode-math`, you `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` and `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}`. Times New Roman also works.